# How to prove the convergence of the cross entropy?

Tags: absolute-convergence

Cross entropy (CE) method is a probabilistic model based method. How to show that it always converges to an exact global optimal solution? How to set the number of samples $N$ and the number of elite samples $N_{\text{elite}}$?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? Actually, I have the proof from Lieber(1998) but I can not understand some details of the proof. Maybe we could collaborate on this?

Comment: I have posted a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4758238/convergence-of-the-cross-entropy-algorithm-i-do-not-understand-the-proof). You can check and if necessary we can chat a bit about the problem.